# white page when using google directions api

Tags: html, api, directions

i am testing a little side project for internal use.

We want to use google directions api to generate een predifined route from amsterdam to belgieplein in bruxels.

here is the code als far as i could create it with the base code google api pages give

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
  width="450"
  height="250">
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
  ?key=AIzaSyC0usSsGXuNajTOjNnMP4yDTmc4P7kqjYk
  &origin=RijsWijkstraat+223,Amsterdam
  &destination=Back-UpStraat+12,Amsterdam
  &avoid=tolls
</iframe>
</html>
```

But all it does is generate a white page. what am i doing wrong here?

I am learing to work with google apis and this one is giving me a headache at the moment.

have changes the origin and directions to almost everything googles api pages says clearly it can handle origin defines the starting point from which to display directions. The value can be either a place name, address or place ID. The string should be URL-escaped, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to City+Hall,New+York,NY. (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.) Place IDs should be prefixed with place_id:.
destination defines the end point of the directions.

So the adress of beginning and ending location should be working but it doesn't.

Can some one point me in a direction to get it working, to be clear it's for learning the apis and what we can do with it in basic internal learning web pages.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your code: The URL should be in a `src` attribute *inside* the `<iframe> ` tag, the closing `</body>` tag is missing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the URL of the iframe has no newline or whitespace character and that it is included as the src attribute in the iframe. It should be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          #map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
           }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe
      width="450"
      height="250"
      frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src ="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyC0usSsGXuNajTOjNnMP4yDTmc4P7kqjYk  &origin=RijsWijkstraat+223,Amsterdam&destination=Back-UpStraat+12,Amsterdam&avoid=tolls"
    </iframe>
    </html>
```

I added this into a jsfiddle here for you to view: https://jsfiddle.net/16q6exkh/

Comment: Thnks, but it still stays white with the change you pointed.

the code snipet when i try to edit my post give </body> after </iframe> but in the text it self it is gone.

Comment: Edited to include removing bad characters from the url. see https://jsfiddle.net/16q6exkh/

Comment: now it with some little tweaking by delete spaces in the src link  in your code it does work. thnks man.

Comment: You're welcome @jubels, as this is the correct answer and links to a working jsfiddle, please mark it correct.  Thanks!

Comment: it does work but is it so that google apis only acept 1 call at a given time i had tried to get the map en a separte iframe with the text directions but it does only show 1.

Comment: i didnt devote it, i cant upfote because my reputation is not high enough

Comment: one mor question about filling the text directions, i have the dropdown underneeth my map with the line.
What i want is connect the dropdown to a mssql database and fill in the value from that database is this possible

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be in a src attribute *inside* the `<iframe>` tag, the closing `</body>` tag is missing in your code, and the URL contains whitespace. If you fix all this, it works:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyC0usSsGXuNajTOjNnMP4yDTmc4P7kqjYk&origin=RijsWijkstraat+223,Amsterdam&destination=Back-UpStraat+12,Amsterdam&avoid=tolls">
</iframe>
</body>

</html>
```